# Cakephp route with regex to render same view but with dynamic URL

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using Cakephp 2.0 and I have a controller setup to accept dynamic url to render the same view :

```
http://domain/some-text-sid-2
http://domain/some-text-sid-3
.
.
.
```

All the content of the pages are changed accordingly by ajax. But when I visit this page or redirect to this page from other page I want to show the view rendered in link mentioned below

```
http://domain/some-text
```

but the URL should remain same. For example if I visit page :

```
http://domain/some-text-sid-2
```

then the view should be of

```
http://domain/some-text
```

but the URL should not change. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the part of the book [on routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)? What kind of routes have you tried?

Comment: @jeremyharris yes I've gone through the Routing documentation. I've not tried any routes yet because I'm not getting the idea how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to add the following route to `/Config/routes.php`:

```
//Matches anything except URLs that include 'my_controller' to prevent looping
Router::redirect('/:text', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'my_action'), array('persist' => ['text'],'text'=>'(?!my_controller)(.*)'));
```

You then extract `text` in your action after the redirect:

```
class MyController extends AppController 
{
    public function my_action() {
        $text = $this->params->named['text'];

        //[...] process action
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Inigo Flores, I worked. I had to do some work but your guidance helped me. Thank you again.